# MySQL FULLTEXT decimal point treated as word separator

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, decimal, token, point

We sell lipo batteries that are 3.7v, 7.4v, 11.1v and the voltage is in a description field. It should be possible to FULLTEXT index that character based field with an FT_MIN_WORD_LEN of 4 and have it contain the tokens "3.7v" etc. and these to be found when searching. All my experiments show that when searching these tokens are missing from the index and I suspect this is because the decimal point is acting as a token separator and no tokens are long enough to meet min length.

What am I doing wrong? Why won't Match Against 3.7v find my entries? Does MySQL FULLTEXT understand the difference between a full stop and a decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-text-adding-collation.html

MySql documentation 12.9.7

Basically there are xml files that control the behaviour of character sets and I was able to change the behaviour of the "." character from punctuation to regular character. Given that the column contains part numbers I changed most of the characters so they were not punctuation creating a new collation set and used that for my part number column. Now works as required.

Comment: The section numbering, "12.9.7", is likely to change; please provide the link and/or title of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Even if FULLTEXT were smart enough to recognize those two uses of `"."`, what about the 5 other uses.  And what about other punctuation marks?  When show `"_"` be part of a "word" and when not?  Etc, etc.

Here's a suggestion for your situation (and many others).

1. Cleanse the data.
2. Put it in the table.
3. Similarly, cleanse the query to be fed into the `AGAINST` clause.

By "cleanse", I mean do any of several things to modify the data to work adequately with FULLTEXT's limitations.

In your one example, I suggest changing `3.7v` or `3.7 v` to `3_7v`.

You may find that some "words" are shorter than min_word_length; for them, you could pad them or do some other kludge.

I recommend you use InnoDB, not MyISAM for all MySQL work.  (And note that the setting there is `innodb_ft_min_token_size`, and it defaults to "3".)